# Raphael -- How to fit the paper size to the browser's window size?

Tags: resize, window, raphael, fullscreen, scaling

I want to change the paper(objects base) size of Raphael to fit the window resizing. [ using Firefox_13.0, Raphael_2.1.0, WindowsXP ]

If it is available, I would like to fit full-screen-mode.

==================================================

(steps)

I created the paper : paper = Raphael(0, 50, 800, 600); // initial width and height are 800 and 600.

I placed objects on the paper.

The window size of browser is checked by windowW = window.innerWidth and winnowH = window.innerHeight (on Firefox).

Scaling value is calculated by sv = windowW/800;

And scaling the paper by paper.scale(sv, sv);

==================================================

(the script)

window.onload = function () {

```
paper = Raphael(0, 50, 800, 600);   
var background = paper.rect(0, 0, 800, 600).attr({fill:'#669999'});

// placing the objects
var circle = ...;
var rect = ...;
var ellipse = ...;

winowW = window.innerWidth;
winowH = window.innerHeight;
sv = winowW/800.

paper.scale(sv, sv);
```

}

==================================================

(result)

Though circle.scale(sv), rect.scale(sv, sv) and ellipse.scale(sv, sv) are valid, paper.scale(sv, sv) and background.scale(sv, sv) are not.

Why this case is happen ?  I can get the window size by window.onresize = function() {...} on real-time. If there are better methods, please tell me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've succeeded by following two points:

1) "paper" itself is not manipulative object. I think we should look it as billboard.

2) use st = paper.set() and put the objects(circle, rect, ...) in it. And use st.scale(sv, sv, 0, 0);

*** third and fourth parameter (0, 0) are very impotent.

(caution)

Serial resizing operation is not good for the function "scale()". Because each of resizing coefficient is piled as the
power of a number. So when one have done 1.1 times resizing operation 5 times, the scale will be 1.1^5.

Answer (score 0):

Use setViewBox()

It should do the work
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox